# Datepicker calendario se queda en en último mes que consulté

Tags: javascript, datepicker, vanilla

Tengo un input datepicker que funciona correctamente, lo que me resulta un poco incómodo o que pueda traer un margen de error al seleccionar una fecha es que al consultar meses anteriores por ej. febrero (hoy es 07-marzo-2024):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo sigue bien, la bronca es que si cierro o me paso a otro input aunque haya seleccionado alguna fecha o no siempre se abre en el mes último que consulté.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon t-filtro">
                <span>FECHA</span>
            </div>
            <input name="" id="liqFechaRem" class="form-control input-sm datepicker liqFechaRem inputsPagoCliente" value=""></input>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Puedes incluir código por favor!

Comment: Recuerda mostrar un [repro] (énfasis en _verificable_).

Comment: hola aqui hace falta que indiques que version de la libreria datepicker esta usando... ya que hay varias con bugs y /o con nombres similares... asique no queda clara en tu pregunta cual es la libreria que estas usando y que llamas datepicker.

Comment: estoy 100% seguro que el error debe estar en algun lugar en tu codigo javascript, html o posiblemente en tu navegador, he aqui un ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/1bhf3uqw/ una de las tantas librerias datepicker en este caso de jquery.

Comment: como podras ver, si navegas este no guarda la navegacion... a menos que el input tenga un valor ... cosa que si lo tiene entonces lo usara como base para mostrar el calendario en abriendolo en ese mes ...

Answer (score -1):

Parece que el datapicker actúa así predeterminadamente.

Lo que puedes hacer es restablecer la fecha con JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#liqFechaRem").datepicker({
        onClose: function() {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, pero el problema no es con el valor sino con el mes que se muestra al reabrir el calendario que se queda en el último mes que dejé cuando lo cerré, pd: igual probé tu solución y no jaló